# Photography Theme - Standard License x 1

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js

I purchased Photography Theme - Standard License x 1 from Vuetify store, but haven´t figured out how to rearrange the photo gallery to get the data from my own Images folder.

At the moment, photographs.js file looks like this:

```
import { make } from 'vuex-pathify'

let image = 247
const categories = [
  'All',
  'Interior',
  'Buildings',
  'Fashion',
  'Nature',
  'Lifestyle',
]

const state = {
  categories,
  filter: 'All',
  picture: null,
  pictures: Array.from({ length: 30 }).map(() => {
    image++

    return {
      **src: `https://picsum.photos/id/${image}/600/350`,**
      category: categories[Math.floor(Math.random() * categories.length)],
    }
  }),
}

const mutations = make.mutations(state)

export default {
  namespaced: true,
  state,
  mutations,
}
```

It takes images from Picsum, but how do I change it so that it would take the images from Images folder? Sorry for such a dumb question..